# how add fancyhdr package to LYX

Tags: latex, lyx

am using LYX on my windows8 OS to generate LATEX documents. When i compile my project an error saying that fancyhdr.sty file can't be found.
Can some one tell me how i add this package please.

Comment: You have to install a (La)TeX distribution that includes [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). That would be either [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) or [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/download). Do you have either? If so, then you need to run the respective package managers and update the distribution to include the package(s) you're short ([`tlmgr`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html) for TeX Live or [MPM](http://docs.miktex.org/faq/packages.html) for MiKTeX).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for responding me. So, i have installed MIKTex , but how can i update it and include fancyhdrsty Can you tell me exactly the steps coz it s my first time using LYX